# Apache searches for old DocumentRoot after editing the config file and restarting it

Tags: apache, http, apache2, httpd.conf, archlinux

I'm using Arch Linux 3.0-ARCH. I've changed my `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` from `/srv/http` to `/var/www`. Then I issued this command:

```
% sudo /etc/rc.d/httpd restart
:: Restarting Apache Web Server                                           [BUSY] 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/srv/http] does not exist
```

Although if I copy files to `/var/www`, they can be seen on localhost.
I've set the correct permissions—`/var/www` is owned by root, its group is `www`. Both I and the `http` user that Apache runs as are a member of that group. Permissions on the directory are `775`.

Comment: Might it be possible that you have other .conf files? Or more than one VirtualHost, and one of them contained the old DocumentRoot path? You have probably checked those ones already, but I think it does not hurt asking. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked these settings?

```
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: +1 because this might be useful if anyone has a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Issue this command:

```
user@arch~>> grep "srv/http" /etc/httpd -R | grep -v vhost | grep -v log
```

This command will tell you what is looking for /srv/http/ directory

if you have vhosts enabled, use this one instead:

```
user@arch~>> grep "srv/http" /etc/httpd -R | grep -v log
```

Comment: I should've thought of that! +1 because this might be useful if anyone has a similar question in the future.